# How to read the values from one flat file and use them in loop in PostgreSQL file?

Tags: psql, postgresql-9.2

The requirement is to read the values from one flat file and use them in for loop to modify the pgSQL queries.

I'm new to PostgreSQL. Please suggest any.

```
CREATE FUNCTION file_vals()
  RETURNS varchar[] AS
  $BODY$
    return (readLines('my_file.txt'))
  $BODY$
  language plpgsql;
DO $ANONYMOUS_BLOCK$ declare
   /* data */
begin
   for c, l in user_c, file_vals()
   loop
    perform x.y(user => c.user, password => l);
     RAISE NOTICE '%', c.user;
   end loop;
end $ANONYMOUS_BLOCK$;
```

**I'm trying to read the values from my_file.txt and also use the values in for loop to insert the values in database(x.y is the psql function) .**

***my_file.txt contains passwords:***

```
a
b
c
d
```

**user_c is cursor, which is having user values.
Need to use both the values i.e, user_c and file_vals in one single for loop statement.**

```
Error:

psql:test.psql:6: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "return"
LINE 4:     return (readLines('my_file.txt'))
            ^
SET
psql:test.psql:20: ERROR:  "c" is not a known variable
LINE 7:    for c, l in user_c, file_vals()
```

Comment: Where is the function `readLines` defined?

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.2? That version is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  - you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I thought readLines is the inbuilt function.

Comment: There is no such function [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) - but it might be easier to use [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) to expose the file as a "table"

Comment: Yes, still using Postgres 9.2 . I will suggest for an upgrade to my team.
For now, could you please suggest anything.

Comment: Could you please give an example .